# ML how to check type of list and give error massage?

Tags: list, types, sml, smlnj, ml

I want to write a sample function that takes a list of any type and returns the head element only if the list is a list of reals.

Otherwise, the function should give the error message

. . . E r r o r : operator and operand don ’ t . . .

```
datatype typeR = Real of real   
fun head(xs) =
    case xs of
         [] => raise List.Empty |  
          Real (x::_) => x:real  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're after – you can't write a function that takes "any type" and then examines the parameter type.
(Writing `head(xs)`, without a type annotation, does not make `head` a function that takes any type. Its type is inferred.)

If you want a function `typeR list -> real`, your main mistake was writing `Real (x::_)` where you should have written `(Real x) :: _`.
That is,

```
fun head(xs) =
  case xs of
      [] => raise List.Empty 
    | (Real x)::_ => x
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
fun head [] =  raise List.Empty
  | head (Real x :: _) = x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(fn x:real list => hd x ) [ 4 ,5 ];
out> error: Type error in function application
(fn x:real list => hd x ) [ 4.0 ,5.0 ];
out> it = 4.0: real
```

Comment: `(fn x:real list => hd x)` does not *take a list of any type*, but only exactly a list of reals. But it does *return the head element only if the list is a list of reals*, and it does produce a type error when not subjected to a list of reals. Alternatively, `hd : real list -> real`.

Answer (score 0):

First some feedback:

- This function is prone to failure since it only accepts a margin of its possible input. Write total functions when you can.
- `raise Empty` would not be descriptive of the situation where the list is non-empty but the first element doesn't contain a real. Another exception should be raised then.
- The following requirement is highly suspicious.

  > Otherwise, the function should give the error message
  >
  > . . . E r r o r : operator and operand don ’ t . . .

  It suggests that you don't differentiate between run-time exceptions and compile-time errors. This is symptomatic for a programming experience with dynamically typed languages where errors and exceptions are all handled after the program is started.

Then some ideas:

Lists in Standard ML are homogeneous, which means they can only be of one type at a time determined in the type-checking phase of compilation. There are a few ways you can deal with that and achieve more dynamic typing;

- [Using algebraic data types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Algebraic_datatypes) [wiki.haskell.org]:

  ```
  datatype dynamic = R of real
                   | I of int
                   | B of bool
                   | S of string
  fun headR [] = raise Empty
    | headR (R r :: _) = r
    | headR _ = raise Domain
  ```

  Then `headR` does not actually accept *any* type. It accepts exactly one, `dynamic`, that can hold any fixed amount of value constructors with parameters of arbitrary type. This mimics heterogeneous lists:

  ```
  val foos = [R 42.0, I 10, B true, S "Hello, World!"]
  ```
- [Using exceptions](http://informallyabstract.blogspot.com/2011/03/heterogeneous-polymophic-structures-in.html) [informallyabstract.blogspot.com]:

  ```
  datatype dynamic = Dynamic of exn
  exception IsReal of real
  fun wrap_real r = Dynamic (IsReal r)
  fun unwrap_real (Dynamic ex) = raise ex handle IsReal r => r
  fun headR (d::_) = unwrap_real
    | headR [] = raise Empty
  ```

  Then `headR` likewise only accepts *one* type, `dynamic`, and fails with whatever exception that was used instead of the `real` wrapper. The difference between using exceptions and a regular `datatype` definition is that exceptions can be extended with new constructors later:

  ```
  exception IsString of string
  fun wrap_string r = Dynamic (IsString r)
  fun unwrap_string (Dynamic ex) = raise ex handle IsString r => r
  val foos = [wrap_real 42.0, wrap_string "This didn't exist before."]
  ```

Neither are preferable because they introduce an unnecessary risk of run-time failure.